# How would I set the y axis to be in millions?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, axis, ticker

Hi I am wondering how you'd set the y axis of a graph to be millions so instead of it showing 5e7 it would show 50 in the same position. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [tick formatters](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) to show the numbers in millions like shown below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

@ticker.FuncFormatter
def million_formatter(x, pos):
    return "%.1f M" % (x/1E6)


x = np.arange(1E7,5E7,0.5E7)
y = x
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x,y)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(million_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(million_formatter)

ax.set_xlabel('X in millions')
ax.set_ylabel('Y in millions')

plt.xticks(rotation='45')

plt.show
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: Hi I wondering How you'd get rid of the .0 at the end of the numbers as well

Comment: Instead of "%.1f  M" use "%f M"